# How to run if once, then run else forever

Tags: java

I'm making an escape room through the console.

I'm trying to run an if statement, and I want to have the `if` statement code run once, and then run the `else` code forever afterward. My program is looped to go back to the same menu after it's finished with a choice the user chooses.

Here is my current code:

```
if (checkBedDraw = false) {

    clear();
    typePrint("You found a \u001b[34mpicklock\u001b[0m! you can only use this on a specific lock, because of its shape. This item has been added to your \u001b[31minventory\u001b[0m.", 50);
    invArray[0] = "picklock";
    checkBedDraw = true;
      
  } else if (checkBedDraw = true) {
  typePrint("You have already checked the drawers, and aqcuired a picklock.", 50);
}
```

`typePrint()` and `clear()` are methods I made.

Comment: post your whole code I mean class

Comment: FYI: `checkBedDraw = true` is an assignment that sets `checkBedDraw` to `true` and not a comparison. If you want to check if the value of `checkBedDraw` is true either use `==` or better just use `if(checkBedDraw)` (And for false `if(!checkBedDraw)`

Comment: `if (checkBedDraw == false)` and not `if (checkBedDraw = false)` and better `if (!checkBedDraw)`

Comment: That's right = it's for assignment in Java and  == to comparison @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: What do you mean by "run the else code forever"? Don't you mean "run the else case always/in every case its reached"? The former implicates some infinite loop which I doubt you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Vendel, Im trying to run the if statement only one time, and once that happens, any other time this code is run, I want it to run the else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `=` and `==`

Be careful, in if statements you have to use `==` as `=` is used to assign a value to a variable.

Also, you are dealing with Boolean so you can just do something like this:

```java
if (checkBedDraw) {
    typePrint("You have already checked the drawers, and aqcuired a picklock.", 50);
} else {
    clear();
    typePrint("You found a \u001b[34mpicklock\u001b[0m! you can only use this on a specific lock, because of its shape. This item has been added to your \u001b[31minventory\u001b[0m.", 50);
    invArray[0] = "picklock";
    checkBedDraw = true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I will check and see if that works.